# How to import global functions from a different files in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm new to vue.js

[image]

I declared my global functions in my index.js and want to slice it out into a folder/name.js and import it back in.

How can I do that ?

Comment: you put the code in the new file, then `import` it where appropriate - just like you do with `modules/auth` for example

Comment: Let's say I cut line 7-86 into a file call global.js, then just simply import it ?

Comment: yes, you could just `import "./global.js"` since there won't be any exports [Import a module for its side effects only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only) ... note: you'll need to import Vue in global.js, of coruse